# error : no resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_width' in package 'android' :(

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I just started to learn app development and i don't know why this error is showing...can someone help..The error is showing in the both buttons.

```
 <LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Your total is 0"
         android:textSize="45sp"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
         />

     <Button
        android:layout_width="250sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_length="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add One" 
        android:id="@+id/bAdd"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_length="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subtract One" 
        android:id="@+id/bSub"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some issues in your layout resource.

If you want to give a specific width you should use dp instead of sp. The latter is meant for text. [Check the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) :)

Another thing that I think is not working is the "android:layout_length" property. I don't think this is a valid property. What did you want to achive with that?

I hope this will solve your problem.